# How do I relocate messages to the C# room?

Tags: bug, chat

The name of the C# room is two characters long, so it doesn't show up in the list of rooms when trying to relocate messages, because I have to enter at least three characters in the search box.

I solved this by temporarily renaming the C# room to "C# room" but I don't want to do this too often as it's annoying.

Comment: Do you have to use the search instead of entering the room straight away?

Comment: I need to enter a room name, otherwise I cannot select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until (if?) this is fixed, you can go around this by adding a blank space after the `C#` in the search box. Just tried it now elsewhere and it's working:

> [image]

Comment: I wonder if this should also be reported as a bug. :P

Comment: @rightfold eh, better not! (looks like the value is being trimmed server side, otherwise there wasn't any match)